# How To Liquefy A Human

Tags: biology, physics, weapons, anatomy, death

Okay, I'm asking this question because in my story, the main bad guy gets killed when he's punched so hard by the heroine that he explodes into bits. His skeleton is broken into many fragments, his armor shatters, and his flesh is broken down into a splatter with chunky bits. Ignoring the fact that he's incredibly strong and durable (he can survive orbital reentry, and hurl people into the Sun), and has an insane healing factor (the explanation is that he used too much of his energy), how hard do you have to punch someone to make them die in a bloody explosion?

Comment: I'm not sure that I see the Worldbuilding element of the question.

Comment: "Explode" and "liqefy" are different things. For example, some parts of the human body, such as the bones or teeth, are solids. Applying pressure to a solid won't transform it into a liquid.

Comment: Does not seem to be a worldbuilding question

Comment: AlexP, the punch is more of breaking every bone in the body and applying enough force to cause it to rip to pieces. That's what I meant.

Comment: @TysonDennis if you want an answer then one clear definition of the effects required and the conditions are required.  The body of the question says the skeleton needs to be broken into many fragments, yet the previous comment specifies that every bone in the body (all 206!) must be broken.  The armour also needs to shatter, but it is not specified what type of armour it is nor what parts of the body it is covering.  One hint - people that fall out of aircraft without parachutes or get hit by speeding cars have lots of broken bones but typically do not fragment.

Comment: edits that invalidate existing answers are NOT allowed @TysonDennis

Comment: (a) Although [we don't all agree about the rule against invalidating answers](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8134/40609), in this case, rather than narrowing your question in a way that happened to invalidate questions, you completely changed the question. For future reference, that's not appreciated. (b) Breaking into a million pieces (or shattering in any form) is something that happens to brittle things, not squishy things like human bodies. (c) The kind of explosion you're looking for couldn't happen unless the body were completely frozen first. (\*continued\*)

Comment: (d) Any punch hard enough to shatter a frozen body would be more likely to simply break the body apart at the point of impact. If not frozen, it would either rip the impact area off (like the head) or simply create a hole. (C.F. *Mythbusters* episodes about gunshots throwing bodies around.) (e) You could consider microwaving the body, converting the water quickly to steam, which wouldn't be the same thing, but at least the body would tear itself apart.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon’s “The Boys” found a way of killing an indestructible human by simply inserting a pound of C4 and a detonator where the sun doesn’t shine.

It’s a matter of being inventive and choosing a different way of achieving your aim and not going with the obvious brute force option.

Comment: I've watched the show. And unless Translucent's skin was weaker on the inside, his insides would be forced out of his outsides like a horrifying tube of Play-Doh.

Answer (score 1):

### It is just not a question of pressure

If you put the body into a pressure chamber and slowly increase the pressure to 1 TPa, the body will not shatter into a large number of bits - though you will have significant overkill, nothing is going to physically dismember the body in that way.

What you need is something that chops up, or dismembers (explosively perhaps) or through massive heating turning the body into a gas or plasma.

Comment: @KerrAvon: This answer answers the original question. The OP changed their mind and replaced the question wholesale.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, but not in a suitably spectacular fashion.

**AQUAMATION**

Kind of like cremation, only without the fire.

Also known as alkaline hydrolysis, it's a process that pretty much turns the body into watery goo and easily crushable bone fragments. The [Font of All Knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkaline_hydrolysis_(body_disposal)) says: "The result is a quantity of green-brown tinted liquid (containing amino acids, peptides, sugars and salts) and soft, porous white bone remains (calcium phosphate) easily crushed in the hand (although a cremulator is more commonly used) to form a white-colored dust." Basically, bottled Soylent Green.

You'll just need to speed up the time factor.